# content of the php file is shown by browser

Tags: php, moodle

I want to open the Moodle's web installer as stated by the document (see step 3). Problem is that, I only see the content of the installer file and not the installer itself! Why such thing happens?

```
root@qemu:~# ls -l /var/www/html/
total 20
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     11321 اوت   31 23:35 index.html
drwxr-xr-x  7 mahmood  mahmood   4096 سپتام  3 15:42 kar3
drwxr-xr-x 49 www-data www-data  4096 سپتام 15 16:42 moodle
root@qemu:~# which php
/usr/bin/php
root@qemu:~# which php7.0 
/usr/bin/php7.0
```

[image]

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 1):

Your file has `.html` suffix while PHP files must have `.php`.

Change to `.php` and enable PHP on server if not already.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) for possible problems.

Comment: There are `install.php` and `index.php` in that folder. Please note that `moodle/` is a folder in the URL